# Encoding test fails in Ant but works in Eclipse

Tags: java, ant, utf-8, junit

I have the following junit tests in an UTF-8 encoded file.

```
public class EncodingTest {

 private static byte[] utf8Bytes;

 private static byte[] utf8Bytes2;

 private static byte[] utf8Bytes3;

 static {
try {
    utf8Bytes = "åæø".getBytes("UTF-8");
    utf8Bytes2 = new byte[] { (byte) 0xc3, (byte) 0xa5, (byte) 0xc3, (byte) 0xa6, (byte) 0xc3, (byte) 0xb8 };
    utf8Bytes3 = "\u00E5\u00E6\u00F8".getBytes("UTF-8");
} catch (final UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    assertTrue(false);
}

 }

 @Test
 public void testUTF8Encoding1() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
assertTrue(Arrays.equals(utf8Bytes, utf8Bytes2));
 }

 @Test
 public void testUTF8Encoding2() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
 assertTrue(Arrays.equals(utf8Bytes2, utf8Bytes3));
 }

 @Test
 public void testUTF8Encoding3() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
 assertEquals(new String(utf8Bytes), new String(utf8Bytes2));
 }

 @Test
 public void testUTF8Encoding4() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
 assertEquals(new String(utf8Bytes2), new String(utf8Bytes3));
 }
}
```

The test fails in ant but works in eclipse. The ANT task I'm using it the following:

```
<target
    name="test"
    depends="compile-tests"
    description="Test the full company tests" >

    <junit fork="yes" haltonfailure="yes" >
        <jvmarg value="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"/>
        <classpath>

            <path refid="test.classpath" />

            <fileset dir="war/WEB-INF/lib/" >

                <include name="*.jar" />
            </fileset>
        </classpath>

        <formatter
            type="plain"
            usefile="false" />
        <!-- to screen -->
        <!-- formatter type="plain" / -->
        <!-- to file -->

        <batchtest>

            <fileset
                dir="test/classes/"
                includes="**/*Test.class" />
        </batchtest>
    </junit>
</target>
```

The output is the following:

```
test:
[junit] Testsuite: com.company.appengine.EncodingTest
[junit] Tests run: 4, Failures: 2, Errors: 0, Time elapsed: 0,028 sec
[junit]
[junit] Testcase: testUTF8Encoding1 took 0,004 sec
[junit]     FAILED
[junit]
[junit] junit.framework.AssertionFailedError:
[junit]     at com.company.appengine.EncodingTest.testUTF8Encoding1(EncodingTest.java:42)
[junit]
[junit] Testcase: testUTF8Encoding2 took 0 sec
[junit] Testcase: testUTF8Encoding3 took 0,001 sec
[junit]     FAILED
[junit] expected:<[Ã¥Ã¦Ã¸]> but was:<[åæø]>
[junit] junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: expected:<[Ã¥Ã¦Ã¸]> but was:<[åæø]>
[junit]     at com.company.appengine.EncodingTest.testUTF8Encoding3(EncodingTest.java:52)
[junit]
[junit] Testcase: testUTF8Encoding4 took 0 sec
```

Any idea?

Comment: are you using same JVM and configuration with ant and with Eclipse?

Comment: how do I know which JVM is ant using?

Comment: Something weird, you're getting junit.framework.AssertionFailedError, but you're using @Test. You should be including org.junit.Assert, not junit.framework.Assert.

Comment: You mean I'm using the wrong JAR ?

Comment: @JordiP.S., Matthew says you are using an incorrect import in your code. and I am saying that ant uses default `java` and `javac` commands, but Eclipse can use their own version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please first make sure that `javac` knows that your source file is encoded in utf-8. If you compile using [javac task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html), supply `encoding` attribute.